# Me.Settings isn't a part of form1

Tags: vb.net, basic

me.settings isn't a part of form1

I have multiple forms, but my startup is my applications form not the login.

But here's my code for my login

```
Public Class Login
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If TextBox1.Text = My.Settings.Username And TextBox2.Text = My.Settings.Password Then
        MsgBox("Works!")
        me.settings.Loggedin = true
    Else
        MsgBox("Missing Username or Password", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Error")

    End If
End Sub
Private Sub LinkLabel1_LinkClicked(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs) Handles LinkLabel1.LinkClicked
    CreateAccount.Show()
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub
End Class
```

I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: Did you mean `My.Settings`?

Comment: BTW - it's not a good idea to store a password in My.Settings.Password because of security thoughts. Please read [Passwords Technical Overview](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh994558(ws.10).aspx).

Answer (score 3):

The error message is informing you that the form called form1 does not have a property called Settings.

I believe you meant to say

```
    My.Settings.Loggedin = true
```

instead of

```
    me.settings.Loggedin = true
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want the LOGIN FORM to be loaded first... then if the username and password are matching, then the APPLICATION FORM will be loaded?
If so, then you have to go to the project's properties and change the STARTUP FORM from your APPLICATION FORM's name into the LOGIN FORM's name.

[image]